# How to perform auto complete textbox operation in selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-ide, functional-testing

I am testing a Magento POS application with Selenium IDE. There is a auto complete textbox, where I need to put the product name. As the auto complete textbox works, when we started typing, it starts searching. I tried a lot, but still I am unable to figure out how to test that in Selenium. I have tried the below command

```
typeAndWait(selector,sony)
verifyText(class=ui-autocomplete:first-child,sony)
click(class=ui-autocomplete:first-child)
```

But it is not working. Any help? I don't understand, what to do ?

Comment: I am just using the selenium only in firefox browser as a extension, not using any driver to use that in any browser

Answer (score 0):

Use `waitForText` instead of `verifyText`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pause or waitfortext` command after type command

instead of `typeandwait` use `type` command

use this code

```
type(selector,sony)
pause 2000
verifyText(class=ui-autocomplete:first-child,sony)
```

Comment: No, auto complete textbox, will search for the corresponding word, when you typing one by one character, If you put the half of the phrase directly by selenium it won't search and won't show the full phrase.

Comment: Selenium ide do not record Auto complete of dropdown, you have to write manually in the textbox field.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to fire the events associated with the textbox.

Comment: About what event you are asking? I ma using auto complete textbox.

Comment: There are some HTML events like Onblur, Onchange, Onpaste, Onkeydown, OnkeyUp, Onkeypress etc..You can check events for your textbox in its HTML...Fire all the events for that textbox..which might help.

Answer (score 0):

instead of type use typekeys command

and insert a new command

click (path of autocomplete text box)

and also insert new commmand

waitforvisible (path of the value to be verified)

now put your command 
verify text(path of the value to be verified,sony)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it might work:

1. Type the required auto-complete name like Sony (use `TypeAndWait` command & add auto-complete id)
2. Use `typeKeysAndWait` command for auto-complete dropdown
3. Click on auto-complete dropdown id

   ```
   TypeAndWait(class=ui-autocomplete:first-child,sony)
   typeKeysAndWait(class=ui-autocomplete:first-child,sony)
   click(class=ui-autocomplete:first-child)
   ```